# How can Beatrice & Prior shoot through the shields?

Tags: plot-explanation, allegiant

In *Allegiant* (2016), Beatrice and Prior use shields to protect themselves from thug bullets:

[image]

So how can Beatrice and Prior shoot through those same shields?

Comment: This is most likely a plot hole

Comment: Same way earlier a fighter plane could shoot through its own propeller, I would guess.

Comment: @mattiav27 Why would it? We have seen the technology from the outside world be utterly miraculous before. There is nothing that speaks against these extremely advanced shields simply being one-way protective or programmed to let bullets from their own guns pass through.